# Multiple Table Select with Where and Limit Returns Same Rows

Tags: mysql

I am trying to select from 2 tables with 'limit = 3' but it returns same rows on first table.

```
atable
------------------
[a_id  -  a_title  -  a_status]
[id1a  -  title1a  -  1]
[id2a  -  title2a  -  1]
[id3a  -  title3a  -  1]

btable
------------------
[b_id  -  b_title  -  b_status]
[id1b  -  title1b  -  1]
[id2b  -  title2b  -  1]
[id3b  -  title3b  -  1]
```

Query

```
SELECT a.a_id
     , a.a_title, b.b_id
     , b.b_title 
  FROM atable a
     , btable b 
 WHERE a_status = 1 
   AND b_status = 1 
 LIMIT 3
```

Results

```
title1a   title1b
title1a   title2b
title1a   title3b
```

But i want like this

```
title1a   title1b
title2a   title2b
title3a   title3b
```

What is the problem in my query?

Edit: After couple of trying i select all rows but how can i implement limit 3 for this query? i am getting syntax errors when i am trying to add limit.

```
SELECT a_title FROM atable LEFT JOIN btable ON (btable.b_id = atable.a_id) WHERE atable.a_status = 1 UNION SELECT b_title FROM btable RIGHT JOIN ON (btable.b_id = atable.a_id) WHERE btable.b_status = 1
```

Comment: You need to `JOIN` the tables based on some related property 
(maybe id?). Otherwise, the database engine has no idea which values in a are related to b so it will return all possible a/b combinations.

Comment: So should i change to columns names same like a.id and b.id, and use join ?

Comment: Note that limit without order by is fairly meaningless

Comment: Column names don't really matter, you can name them however you wish. I don't know your specific case, but if for example `a_id` is related to `b_id`, then I would do `SELECT ... FROM atable a JOIN btable b ON (a.a_id = b.b_id) WHERE ...`.

Comment: There is no relationship between a and b. I just want to select them in a query

Comment: Joining completely unrelated tables will only produce a bunch of unrelated combinations. Do with that what you will. Overall, this sounds like a poor design choice. If you're just looking to match rows 1-to-1 between two tables, fine but that will only give you headaches later. What if the tables have uneven rows? What if the order of items changes? Relations are the way to go when working with *Relational* Databases such as MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You are *cross joining* two tables, which mean data is multiplied by **3x3**. As a result, you need to expect 9 rows to be displayed.

This describes the reason of getting three results starting with `title1a`.

If `atable` and `btable` has relationship you need to join both tables and then you can get proper result.

Comment: There is no relationship between table a and table b.

Comment: I understood that there is no physical relationship between tables. Is there any logical relationship between two tables?

Answer (score 0):

You need to join on something(s) that can link records 1-1.

Your current query cross joins all of atable with status 1 to all of btable with status 1.

For example, based on your example, on the first 6 characters.

```
SELECT a.a_id, a.a_title, b.b_id, b.b_title 
FROM atable a
JOIN btable b 
  ON LEFT(b.b_title, 6) = LEFT(a.a_title, 6) AND b.b_status = 1 
WHERE a.a_status = 1 
LIMIT 3
```

The LIMIT has nothing to do with it.  It's just to a way to tell MySql how many rows it may return from the complete result.  And often a LIMIT is used in combination with a ORDER BY.